# Printer sends two jobs to the queue. One without a status or port. Won't print until ghost job is canceled

Tags: windows, printing, printer

I have an HP LaserJet P1505 that has been giving me some grief on a 64-bit machine.  After removing drivers and deleting devices, I reinstalled it.   Test page works fine.  If I print from another application, it sends two jobs to the print queue - a "normal" job and a "ghost" job.  Image is below.  Once I cancel the ghost job, the other one will print.

This is on a Windows 7 workstation.

[image]

Comment: It will be important to know what version of Windows you are using. Does this happen in all applications or only Excel? How about Notepad?

Comment: All office applications.  Notepad will send two, but the second one disappears on its own.  Printing from Office, the ERP, Adobe, all has this behavior.

Comment: I updated my comment while you were answering it...What version of Window are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try enabling "LPR mode" under Printer properties and check your results?.

Go to Devices and Printers > select and right click the printer in subject > choose "Printer Properties" > Port tab > select 'LPR' and click ok. Now, try sending a print out and check your results.

[image]